# How to Decrypt Values in Pentaho which were encrypted using custom secret key

Tags: encryption, pentaho

I have a problem like this, I'm using Pentaho COmmunity edition for some reporting and analysis purposes. In my side I have a table with encrypted values which were encrypted using a secret key. When I fetch data using Pentaho those values comes as encrypted values. How can I get the decrypted values. Is there a work around.

Comment: Do you even have the decryption key? If not, you cannot do much about it.

Comment: yes I have the decryption key

Answer (score 0):

If the encryption is DES, AES or TripleDES you can use the "Symmetric Cryptography" step in the transformation. There is also a PGP decryption step if that's what you have.

Anything else probably needs a custom Java step that loads the needed libraries and executes the decrypt.

Comment: @yasiru-nilan Just a note - still there's a question to consider - if there's a policy or regulation enforcing the data encryption, then won't a transformation (decryption) step violate the policy (or regulation) when storing the data in plain?